# How to combine row filtering and highlight functionality in React tables?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to create this functionality in React Tables:

[image]

This functionality has been created for another table that is **not using useFilters**. But now I want to use React **useGlobalFilter** functionality for this.

I followed [this tutorial](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/filtering?file=/src/App.js) for that purpose, and now my tables are being correctly filtered using globalFilters.

But the highlight functionality is not working properly. My cell render receives an HTML like this:

```
<mark>Reg</mark>istered
```

so if I try to filter by: **Regist**ered, it will never work, as plain text contains `<mark>` HTML tags.

So I'm trying to combine both functionalities playing with Column filters **based on dataSource instead of column value**, but with no luck.

Note:

- My render functionality accepts any component to render content. That's why I can draw HTML content inside.
- I want my filter to search based on dataSource or a specific value I set

Any clues on how to get this?